# Cytoscape use of external CSS classes

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'm not clear on what the "classes" property does after reading the [Cytoscape documentation](http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/#notation/elements-json) multiple times. Should I be able to use an external CSS file with a corresponding class defined, and assign that to a node in my Cytoscape code, for example?

I would like to define a different class for potentially each node. Can anyone shed light on how this works? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set a [stylesheet](http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/#style) at [initialisation](http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/#core/initialisation), which can use [class selectors](http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/#selectors/group-class-amp-id) etc.

Comment: OK, thanks Max. As I understand it then, "set a stylesheet" here means  setting the css property of an element within Cytoscape, and does not mean referencing a styles.css file somewhere. I figured out how to set the styles I am after at initialization via code, so that will work. Keep up the good work.

Comment: Your cy.js stylesheet is used on the graph much as a CSS stylesheet would be used on a HTML document.  You can create a "styles.css" file, pull it down from the server, and specify its string value to cy.js.  Alternatively, you can embed the stylesheet in your JS (in any of the formats supported: JSON, string stylesheet, or functional).  Your stylesheet should specify rules for styling the elements in the graph.  Generally, per-element styling is avoided except for one-off styles.